# Vertical Align (valign) bootstrap4 cells

Tags: bootstrap-4

In one of the `td` I have a large button. Which makes the row grow to this buttons height. I want to vertically align all cells content to be middle. However it's not working. I tried the `valign` attribute on each `td`:

Anyway to vertically align the td's? Without tricks like turning each td into flexbox `class="d-flex justify-content-center"` or nesting tables?

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col" class="border-top-0">Building</th>
            <th scope="col" class="border-top-0">Distance</th>
            <th scope="col" class="border-top-0">Monthly Cost</th>
            <th scope="col" class="border-top-0"></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td valign="middle">DF Center</td>
            <td valign="middle">2.2mi</td>
            <td valign="middle">$35</td>
            <td class="text-right" valign="middle"><button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg">Select</button></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: try this boostrap class: class="align-middle"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `class="align-middle"`...

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col" class="border-top-0">Building</th>
            <th scope="col" class="border-top-0">Distance</th>
            <th scope="col" class="border-top-0">Monthly Cost</th>
            <th scope="col" class="border-top-0"></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="align-middle">DF Center</td>
            <td class="align-middle">2.2mi</td>
            <td class="align-middle">$35</td>
            <td class="text-right align-middle">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg">Select</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/oRuZLixu1L

To horizontally center all head and body cells..

```
.table thead th,
.table tbody td {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Whoa thank you! That worked!! How come `valign` isn't respected? Just curious what is breaking that. (it says i have to wait 7min before accepting answer, will accept in a second)

Comment: Is there a trick to center a whole column? Or do I have to add `text-center` to each `td` and each `th`?

Comment: Thank you @Zim! I didn't realize we had to break out to stylesheet! Awesome learning thank you.